# EmguCV is not working after recent windows update

Tags: c#, emgucv, windows-update

I have downloaded and installed EmguCV. and trying to run the examples attached with it. But it is giving "**The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception**" Exception for every sample project. It was working fine before windows updates. 
I have tried to reinstall it again but still it didn't work.
I am implementing it in c# with vs2017
Please tell me what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar Exception while running the code after attaching the EmguCV Library, but when I install it from NuGet Manager it got resolved.

**Steps:-**

Go to Solution Explorer of the project **->** Right Click on References and click on Manage NuGet Packages **->** In the Browse Section just write Emgu Cv and install it.

It will automatically add the refereneces and It will work.

Hope That helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: This solve your problem?

Comment: Actually, I have installed some windows required service packs, and it is working now. I think those service packs were making the problem.